# I just started with firebase and have problem with orderBy desc function when getting data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the function orderBy when passing the "desc" parameter, it does not return data, but when passing "asc" or blank, there is data.

```
const getListProduct = async () => {
    const products = await fs
      .collection("products")
      .orderBy("createAt", "desc") //problem is here.It just works orderBy("createAt", "asc") or orderBy("createAt")
      .startAfter(0)
      .limit(5)
      .get();
    let listProduct = [];

    for (let snap of products.docs) {
      let data = snap.data();
      data.ID = snap.id;
      listProduct.push({ id: snap.id, ...data });
      if (products.docs.length === listProduct.length) {
        
        setListData(listProduct);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The value in [`startAfter()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#startafter) must be either a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#startafter) or the value of field to start this query after. If `createAt` field is a Timestamp then it must be `startAfter(<DATE_OBJ>)` or snapshot of document from last query but you are passing a number. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const products = await fs
  .collection("products")
  .orderBy("createAt", "desc")
  .startAfter(new Date(2022, 8, 17, 6, 54, 0)) // for testing Date(year, date, month, hh, mm, ss)
  .limit(5)
  .get();
```

This should return all products where `startAfter` is less than the provided timestamp in descending order.

---

Alternatively, you can store snapshot of the last query in your state and use it as shown below:

```
let lastSnapshot = null;

const q = fs.collection("products").orderBy("createAt", "desc")

if (lastSnapshot) {
  // Query has been executed before, use last snapshot
  q.startAfter(lastSnapshot);
}

const products = await q.limit(5).get();
```